# User login control with global variables and JS

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, global-variables

BACKGROUND: I am creating a site that will run on an embedded device that provides an interface for the user to interact with several functions on the site.  These functions on the HTML site will interface to a Python script which will then control external physical devices connected to the embedded device.

WHAT I HAVE SO FAR: I have a login splash screen which authenticates the user if only if their username and password match a static string in a JS file.  Each individual .html file has a corresponding .js file.

WHAT I WANT: I want a global.js file which every other individual .js file can read/write to a 'loginState' variable which will state if the user was properly authenticated on "/login.html".  This way, if the user navigates to "/home.html" manually I can see if 'loginState' is the correct value when the page loads, indicating the user did authenticate.  If 'loginState' is not the correct value, I will know the user did not properly authenticate and will direct them to "/login.html".

I know this is an unconventional way of implementing a login system without using php or ASP.NET but this is my first site and I am trying to use "vanilla" HTML and JS.

ISSUE: I've implemented the following code below and I cannot get 'loginState' to act as a global variable.

global.js

```
var loginState = "false";
```

login.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>
```

login.js

```
if(username == valid && password == valid) {
  window.location.pathname = '/home.html'
  loginState = "true"
}
else {
  console.log("Invalid credentials!")
  loginState = "false"
}
```

home.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="home.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>
```

home.js

```
window.onload = function() {
  if(loginState != "true") {
    window.location.pathname = '/login.html'
  }
};
```

QUESTION:  Do I have some sort of mistake in my JS, or does a global variable not work across files in JS?  Is there a better way to accomplish my goal without using ASP.NET?  The solution does not need to be super secure, the device won't be exposed to the Internet.

Comment: Hello, variables can be accessed from another script as long as they are in your window context. Unless your loginState variable is declared within the scope of a function it should be accessible from anywhere, as long as your script is added to your HTML. Are you having problems finding this loginState from both login.js and home.js?

Comment: If you want to maintain state between different HTML pages, you need to use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`. Javascript variables do not persist between pages.

Comment: Managing authentication in JS is not safe. The user can just go into DevTools and type `loginState = "true"` in the console.

Comment: BTW, for true/false values you should use booleans, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented `sessionStorage` to store the state of `loginState` and `localStorage` to store the users theme setting `light` or `dark`.